# FlatList automatically scrolls to first when data is too large in horizontal mode (RTL)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

### Environment

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
    Memory: 1.35 GB / 7.87 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.15.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.17.3 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.4.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
```

React Native version: **0.60.4**

### Code

```
<FlatList
    style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginHorizontal: -wp('3%'),
        zIndex: 40
    }}
    initialNumToRender={10}
    data={this.state.data}
    horizontal={true}
    key={item => item.groupNo}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    ref={ref => (this.flatList = ref)}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Item item={item} />
    )}
/>
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1. Added some data to my FlatList
2. Add horizontal={true} property to flatlist
3. Set `I18nManager.allowRTL(true)`
4. Set `I18nManager.forceRTL(true)`
5. Make my renderItem component extend as PureComponent.
6. Using Real Android Device

As you see below when my app is running on RTL direction `FlatList` automatically scrolls to top/first of the list but LTR direction is OK!

**RTL:**

[image: RTL_GIF]

**LTR:**

[image: LTR_GIF]

Answer (score 1):

I also have a same this problem, and my solution (you add them in your Flatlist).
Hope help you.
This link maybe help you improve your list:
https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips

```
getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
        { length: LECTURE_ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: LECTURE_ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index }
      )}
maxToRenderPerBatch={20}
initialNumToRender={10}
windowSize={10}
removeClippedSubviews={true}
```

Comment: Thanks I will check that

Answer (score 1):

it's a major issue, also causes a problem with react-native-calendars.

for now, you can check onScroll event, on init it causes major scroll event, you can simply return false there and block the scroll.
I hope a better solution will come in the next verisons.

Answer (score 0):

try to make the trick as explained in example with onEndReached method.
https://snack.expo.io/r1NMSxFwr

Also try to play with initialNumToRender.

Comment: I have tried all of them! The problem is that just direction of app will make sense!

Answer (score 0):

the best and easy way is to install this npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autoscroll-flatlist

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).